# Update an Option Outside the Redux Panel

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I'm trying to update a Redux option outside of Redux Option panel. I'm following [this official guide](http://docs.reduxframework.com/core/advanced/update-an-option-outside-the-options-panel/), but it's **outdated**.

In newest version of Redux, there is no `new Redux_Framework_sample_config();` line in config file. There is a static `Redux` class and this class don't have any `set()` method.

So, how can I update an option outside of Redux option panel?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = get_option( 'opt_name' );
$data['key_i_want_to_change'] = 1;
update_option( 'opt_name', $data );
```